# Can I change the MAC Address on my Airport Extreme WiFi Router?

Tags: mac-address, airport-extreme

I am trying to do some [diagnostics on my Time Warner Wideband Internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/356329/why-does-my-time-warner-ip-address-change-depending-on-device). To do so I would like to spoof the MAC Address on my [AirPort Extreme WiFi Router](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/).

**I cannot find a way to alter the MAC address on the AirPort Extreme using the [AirPort Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Utility).**

Is this possible? Is there a way to set the MAC address on an Airport Extreme?

My AirPort is currently using the 7.6 Firmware Upgrade.

**UPDATE:**

The reason I wan't to spoof the MAC address on my AirPort Extreme is to diagnose an issue with the IP address range that Time Warner gives me when I connect their SMC cable modem to one of my devices. Please refer to the first link in my question.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible at all (also, see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2738296?start=0&tstart=0)). Wouldn't it make sense to try with another computer and spoof the MAC address from there?

Comment: Or, as an alternative: spoof the address [of that MacBook](http://superuser.com/questions/356329/why-does-my-time-warner-ip-address-change-depending-on-device)? (For which I don't know the answer either, but it feels easier...)

Comment: @Arjan What I want to do is spoof the address of the AirPort to match the MacBook to see if I can force the IP range when I reboot the cable modem.

Comment: Sure, but if the expected outcome is indeed true, then doing it the other way around would also proof it? (The MacBook getting the IP range that so far you saw for the router.) That would not change the question though, but it might be easier to find (Google) ways to spoof the MacBook's MAC address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way, and has never been a way, to change the MAC address on any model of AirPort base station, including Time Capsules.

Answer (score -1):

What about such utility? It looks like it solves the problem.

http://macpod.net/software/AirPortExtremeMACAddressChanger.php

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [guidelines on recommending software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers): in particular, you need to explain how the software you're suggesting solves the problem and how to use the software to do that.